# Why do i get undefined when console.log(object.property) of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongoose, javascript-objects

Why am i getting **undefined** when `console.log(object.property)`?

This is my **code**:

```
const adminusersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
const adminusers = mongoose.model('adminusers', adminusersSchema, 'adminusers');

app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
    let result = await adminusers.find();
    console.log(result[0]);
    console.log(result[0].mail);
    res.send();
});
```

And this is the output in console:

```
Connecting to DB
Connected to DB
Server on port: 3000
{
  _id: 6110430c94569f3dfc90146d,
  mail: 'admin@user.com',
  password: 'admin123'
}
undefined
```

If i try JSON.parse i get an error:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
    let result = await adminusers.find();
    console.log(result[0]);
    console.log(JSON.parse(result[0]).mail);
    res.send();
});
```

**SyntaxError: Unexpected token _ in JSON at position 4**

I can't see what is the problem with my code, because if i do a:

```
app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{

    let object = {
        'test': 'approved',
        'problem': 'solved'
    }

    console.log(object)
    console.log(object.test);

    // let result = await adminusers.find();
    // console.log(result[0]);
    // console.log(JSON.parse(result[0]).mail);
    // res.send();
});
```

My **output** is:

```
Connecting to DB
Connected to DB
Server on port: 3000
{ test: 'approved', problem: 'solved' }
approved
```

Comment: Are you sure the object key and your JS code uses the regular string `mail`, and not something with weird invisible characters? For that reason, also always include your console output in a code block instead of an image. **Images are bad if they can be avoided.**

Comment: Try parsing as `JSON.parse(result[0]).mail;`, Seeing the output, it seems like a parsing issue.

Comment: Try let result = await adminusers.find()/findOne().lean()

Answer (score 1):

I would try turning the mongoose document into a regular javascript object, you can use `.toObject()` or if you plan on returning it from your endpoint as JSON then perhaps use `.toJSON()` instead. https://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#toObject i.e.

```js
const adminusersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
const adminusers = mongoose.model('adminusers', adminusersSchema, 'adminusers');

app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
    const result = await adminusers.find();
    const objectResult = result.toObject();
    console.log(objectResult[0]);
    console.log(objectResult[0].mail);
    res.send();
});
```

Another option as suggested in the comments would be to use the `lean()` function on your query, as `Documents returned from queries with the lean option enabled are plain javascript objects, not Mongoose Documents` - https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean

I.e.

```js
const adminusersSchema = new mongoose.Schema({});
const adminusers = mongoose.model('adminusers', adminusersSchema, 'adminusers');

app.post('/login', async (req, res)=>{
    let result = await adminusers.find().lean();
    console.log(result[0]);
    console.log(result[0].mail);
    res.send();
});
```